# How can I stop a running fabric tail task?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask server serving an api for running fabric tasks. So a post to url /tail, would run a tail on multiple hosts, in parallel, and output the result in a file on the local disk.

```
@parallel
def tail_task(output_fh, tla, grep):
    tail_cmd = 'tail -F /var/log/someservice/*-server.log | grep -i INFO'
    try:
        sudo(tail_cmd, stdout=output_fh)
    except Exception, e:
        print e.message
        return "FAIL!!"
```

which I call from

```
@app.route('/tail', methods=['POST'])
def tail():
    output_fh = open('tail_output.log', 'w')
    result = execute(tail_task, hosts=hosts_list)
```

The post works, so making a post call to that url starts writing the file on disk. The issue I'm having is I have no idea how to stop that task. So if the call comes, it will be waiting forever for a response as the sudo(tail_cmd) will not exit. Any idea how to stop it? Or how I should go about doing this?

I'm then serving a get url which reads content from that file and streams it with:

```
@app.route('/get_tail', methods=['GET'])
def stream():
    def generate():
        with open('tail_output.log') as f:
            while True:
                yield f.read()
                time.sleep(0.01)

    return app.response_class(generate(), mimetype='text/event-stream')
```

Comment: Did you find a solution to this ?

Comment: I do not recall.